# Airport Disk - How can I access it over the Internet without iCloud or Back to my Mac?

Tags: airport, file-sharing

Airport Disk -  How can I access it over the Internet without iCloud or Back to my Mac?

I have enabled the "access disk over WAN" option but when I try the ip nothing happens.

The ip is correct, I always have the same one and I've used it to connect remotely to my desktop.

Anyone? I've read somewhere Apple disabled this?!

PS. I've already read this [Access disk attached to Airport Extreme over internet?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/117135/access-disk-attached-to-airport-extreme-over-internet) and it does not fix my issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you specify volume name in the afp url?

http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4538

Comment: I'll try it and report back.